# How to fix error: Unhashable type: 'Series'?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, series

Below is the dictionary I have created,

```
flag = {'No': 0, 'N': 0, 'Y': 1, 'Yes': 1}

New_Product_Launch = flag[
    final_input_optimization[
        (final_input_optimization['Brand'] == Campaign_Details.iloc[0]['Brand'])
        & (final_input_optimization['Banner'].isin([banner, banner_1]))
    ]['NPD Flag']
]
```

I am getting below error:

> Error: unhashable type: 'Series'

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of `final_input_optimization`. You likely want to [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) the dictionary, you almost surely can't index it directly.

Comment: Please format your questions properly.

Comment: You are trying to use a pd.Series as a dictionary key. But a pd.Series is not hashable. And the `flag` dictionary doesn't look like you want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `final_input_optimization` is a DataFrame, so

```py
flag_keys = final_input_optimization[
        (final_input_optimization['Brand'] == Campaign_Details.iloc[0]['Brand'])
        & (final_input_optimization['Banner'].isin([banner, banner_1]))
    ]['NPD Flag']
```

then `flag_keys` above would would be a series, and you're trying to execute `flag[flag_keys]`, which is probably what's raising the error.

As suggested in [one of the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76539873/how-to-fix-error-unhashable-type-series#comment134952327_76539873), you probably want to use [`.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) like

```py
New_Product_Launch = flag_keys.map(flag)
```

or

```py
New_Product_Launch = final_input_optimization[
        (final_input_optimization['Brand'] == Campaign_Details.iloc[0]['Brand'])
        & (final_input_optimization['Banner'].isin([banner, banner_1]))
    ]['NPD Flag'].map(flag)
```

Note that the resultant `New_Product_Launch` should also be a series, and also that I can't be sure of any of this without a relevant sample of `final_input_optimization`, as well as the values of `Campaign_Details.iloc[0]`, `banner` and `banner_1`.